# Can we add an acknowledgment to a paper after it has been published?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, acknowledgement

Like it has been mentioned, I wanted to know if it is possible to add an acknowledgment after the paper has been accepted

We even attended the conferences a few days back

Comment: accepted or published?

Comment: Accepted.
I think around 2 weeks back

Comment: Then accept Allure’s answer.

Comment: What does the "_we even attended the conferences a few days back_" have to do with a paper? O_o

Answer (score 2):

What stage is your paper at?

If your paper has been **published**: no, you cannot. It's too late. The electronic files have already been distributed and it's possible the hardcopy versions have been printed as well.

If your paper has been **accepted** but not published: you can, but hurry. Tell the editor/publisher you want to add an acknowledgements, and give them the exact text. Chances are they won't object. The earlier you do this the more convenient it'll be for the publisher. If you wait till after you've sent in author corrections, they might say it's too late.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on the publisher. If it is a conference paper it may be that the editors of the proceedings will permit revisions (soon) after the conference if the proceedings are published later.

But that is completely up to them, and you have to ask them to get a valid answer. The same is true in general, though for print publications, the most you can hope for is a note in a future issue, I suspect.